# Internal test track application unpublished

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to upload an internal test tracking application on google play store.

- It is been almost 16 hours and the application isn't yet published but I got a notification that the application is live.
- I want only the testers to download the application for testing. I have added their email ids.
- Problem faced.....I can not get the download link unless the application is published. Do I have to do any more process in order to get the download link? How long will I have to wait?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you put the APK/Bundle on the test track and add people to the track, you are given a link on that page that your testers have to follow to accept receiving the test version of your app.

Send the link to your testers, and once they agree and after some propagation delay, they'll be able to download the app from the Play Store.

The address is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.package.name.here (replace the package name)

Comment: I know rest of the procedure after publishing. The question is what should be done after roll out so that the application get published and i can share the link? Should i wait for the application to get published which is taking really long time? or should i do some other process in order to get it published?

Comment: You mentioned that you had a notification saying that the app was live, so the app should already be available to the testers.